# Wrong ProviderUserId on WSO2 Identity Server, using SAML2 Web SSO

Tags: oauth, server, wso2, identity, saml-2.0

I've configured `SAML2 Web SSO` to redirect the user login from an external form to our `WSO2 Identity Server`. We are using `OAuth` on the `WSO2 Identity Server`.

Recently, we've changed the `OAuth ProviderUserId`. We were using the email address and now we are using a `GUID`.

When the users are redirected from the external form to `WSO2` and we try to get the user data from `OAuth` (using the access token), the subject we get is the email address and not the `GUID`. The login fails.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm supposing that you are using Identity Server 5.0.0.

In the configuration of the service provider you can set the claims you want.

- Try to set the `Role Claim URI:` to the claim coresponding to GUID.

Then it should be this field who is set when requesting a token.